# How can I get my system to boot after cloning used Macrium Reflect?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd, macrium

I got a new SSD and I was trying to migrate my OS from my HDD to my new SSD and I ran into a problem: The PC didn't want to boot from the new SSD even after changing the boot sequence and running the boot fix from the USB flash drive that I created earlier using Macrium Reflect.

But when I was looking online I found that for most people, the system disk is only 100MB-ish size.

So I figured I might have messed things up during my Windows 10 installation, is there any way to fix this without messing it up even more?

Macrium Reflect interface:

[image: Macrium interface]

Diskpart results:

[image: diskpart results]

Comment: How did you do the migration?

Comment: i used Macrium and followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHCENfs87F4

Comment: If you copied the entire disk, not a partition, it's weird that it failed. Try another product, for example [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).

Comment: i didn't copy the entire disk, i only copied the C partition  , because my HDD is only 256 gigs in size

Comment: To make a disk bootable, you need to copy *everything*. AOMEI adjusts for different disk sizes, and I believe that Macrium does it too.

Comment: by everything you mean the boot drive and the system drive right? because otherwise it wouldn't make sense

Comment: By everything I mean everything - do a disk copy, not a partition copy.

Answer (score 0):

To make a disk bootable, you need to clone *everything*.

Most serious cloning software AOMEI adjust for different disk sizes.

Macrium probably does it, and
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).